# send email to current user email in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, email, firebase-authentication

In this code send email to specific email but I want send email to current user email
I connect my project with firebase.

```
      sendMail() async {
      String username = 'example@gmail.com';
      String password = 'axneqgkraxm';

      final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);

      final message = Message()
    ..from = Address(username, 'testing')
    ..recipients.add('uu500oi@gmail.com')
    ..subject = 'Receipt :: ${DateTime.now()}'

    ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'

    ..html = html
        .replaceFirst('{{title}}', 'this will be the title')
        .replaceFirst('{{price}}', '20')
        .replaceFirst('{{hours}}', '2:00 PM')
        .replaceFirst('{{description}}', 'this is description');

     try {
     final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);

    print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
      } on MailerException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    print('Message not sent.');

    for (var p in e.problems) {
      print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
          }
      }
```

anyone can solve it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
sendMail() async {
  if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
    String username = 'example@gmail.com';
    String password = 'axneqgkraxm';

    final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);

    final message = Message()
      ..from = Address(username, 'testing')
      ..recipients.add(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email)
      ..subject = 'Receipt :: ${DateTime.now()}'
      ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'
      ..html = html
        .replaceFirst('{{title}}', 'this will be the title')
        .replaceFirst('{{price}}', '20')
        .replaceFirst('{{hours}}', '2:00 PM')
        .replaceFirst('{{description}}', 'this is description');

    try {
      final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);

      print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      print('Message not sent.');

      for (var p in e.problems) {
        print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the email address of the current user from Firebase Authentication with:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
  print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email);
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) and the reference document for Firebase's [`User` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html).